# Steady Couette flow where the moving wall suddenly stops

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, viscosity, order-of-magnitude

Let it be a [planar Couette flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Couette_flow) for an incompressible fluid with dynamic viscosity $\mu$ and density $\rho$ that has reached the steady-state. Assuming that the plates are placed at the $xz$ plane, separated by a distance $h$, and that the upper one is moving along the $x$ axis with constant speed $U$, in absence of pressure gradients, the velocity field will be given by

$$
u(y)=U \frac{y}{h}
$$

I'm trying to estimate how much time would require the fluid to stop if the moving plate suddenly stopped. I see that this is related to the magnitude of the convective term $\mathcal{O} ((\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla)\mathbf{u})$ and the viscous term $\mathcal{O}(\nu \nabla^{2} \mathbf{u})$. However, how might they relate to the time required?

Note: in White's *Viscous Fluid Flow* book it is said that the *Steady Couette flow where the moving wall suddenly stops* is indeed one of the few known exact solutions for the Navier-Stokes equation; I haven't been able to find it, but I would be interested just on an estimation of the order of the time.